# Rank all items of a set in Redis

Tags: database, nosql, redis

I've been experimenting with the command ZREVRANK in redis and it seems to work great on single items but I can't seem to find a way of returning the ranks of all items in a set:

"item1" score:3
"item2" score:5
"item3" score:2
"item4" score:3
"item5" score:7

ranked results:

"item5" score:7 rank:0
"item2" score:5 rank:1
"item1" score:3 rank:2
"item4" score:3 rank:2
"item3" score:2 rank:3

I wonder if anyone has found a way of achieving this?

Comment: not sure why you cannot use zrange or zrevrange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at not using zrange or zrevrange?
zcard will give you the total number of elements in the set.

Comment: I have tried zevrange but it doesn't identify ties e.g. in my example "item 1" and "item 4" have scores of 3, but on executing zrevrange all items come out numbered 1,2,3,4,5 with no ties?

Comment: I believe lexicographical order is used for elements with equal scores.  Is that not what you are observing?

Comment: No I think I may have thought this was happening, I can see it's definitely returning a different rank for same score entries now.  Thanks for your help, I wonder if you have any idea how I could efficiently evaluate ties from this ordering?

Comment: can you possibly share the actual insert into the sorted set (if its not "item1", "item2" etc.).  I get results in lexicographical order in case of score ties.  If you are getting all the results in sorted fashion & you just need to re-sort the ties, you may wish to look into writing your own comparison for the ties.  In order to identify the ties, I think you should only have to check for the previous item (even if there are multiple items at the tied score) just to figure out the second item in the tie & proceed from there till you get all the items in the tie.